# How do I extract data from a Word document into a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, json, parsing, csv, document

I have a set of word documents that contains trivia questions in a question/answer format. I want to be able to extract these from the word document into a database format such as JSON, CSV, or MySQL with a question column and an answer column. How would I go about doing this? (Script?)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution will be to parse the .doc file and store it in comma separated file and then you can import it in MYSQL. The parsing depends on the format(delimiters used) of your word document file.

Comment: What language would I use to parse a doc?

Comment: Language depends on you. You can use VB, Java, PHP whatever you want. First you should copy the contents of the .doc in a text file and then read that text file then parse it and save it in .csv  :)

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late but you can copy the word table to excel and then use https://convertexcel.net/ to convert it to JSON, CSV or HTML